# about return parent instance(?)

Tags: python

```
def something_callable(**kwargs):
    def _wrap(something, **kws):
        return something
    
    return _wrap


class TestClass:
    
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = x + y
    
    call = something_callable(value='value')


test_class = TestClass('x', 'y')
what = test_class.call()


# it is True...how?
print(what == test_class)
```

something looks like some classmethod..

I don't know how "something" is assigned to parents instance..

(I think it's strange to call "parents instance", it is not inheritance)

And why raise type error when forcibly assigning the something?

```
what = test_class.call(something=None)
# raise TypeError: _wrap() got multiple values for argument 'something'
```

Please let me know if there are any words that call these techniques.

Comment: Note that `call = something_callable(...)` is essentially the same as `call = lambda self: self`, and that `test_class.call(something=None)` is essentially equivalent to `TestClass.call(test_class, something=None)`

Comment: I think the example is not a [mre]. You can remove `__init__`  to make the example more *minimal*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have chosen a nice thing to analyze. To make it even simpler, let's remove all code that is irrelevant and unused.

- I have removed the `__init__` part of the code, because it is not relevant. It just assigns properties and it's trivial.
- I have removed `**kwargs` and `**kws` because they are unused.

The code is then

```
def something_callable():
    def _wrap(something):
        return something
    return _wrap


class TestClass:
    call = something_callable()


test_class = TestClass()
what = test_class.call()

# it is True...how?
print(what == test_class)
```

Let's go throught it like the Python interpreter does:

1. `def something_callable():` defines a method.
2. `def _wrap(something):` defines a method inside a method. That's possible because Python methods are first class objects.
3. `return something`: the wrap() method simply returns anything it was given. Keep in mind that `something` is the first argument.
4. `return _wrap`: note the missing braces: this returns the method itself! It's like a function pointer in C++. It's very important to understand this line of code. It does **not** run the method and return `something`. This method will be run later.
5. `class TestClass:`: defines a class with ...
6. `call =` : a member with the name `call`. That might be anything: an `int`, `str`, `list`, ... whatever we assign to it.
7. `something_callable()`: calls a method. Because of the braces this actually runs the method. We get back: the method `_wrap`. The function pointer to it!
8. `test_class = TestClass()`: create an instance
9. `what = test_class.call`: access the property `call` of the object, which is a function pointer.
10. `()`: And actually call it (that's what the braces do). Since we call the method on an object, the first parameter passed to the method is the object. Usually we call that `self`, just you called it `something`.

Perhaps a bit of renaming and moving helps. The code below is a bit simpler, but basically equivalent:

```
def instance_method(self):
    return self

def give_me_a_method():
    return instance_method

class TestClass:
    method = give_me_a_method()

test_class = TestClass()
what = test_class.method()

# it is True...how?
print(what == test_class)
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. I've been working as a Python developer for quite a long time, but I never knew it was possible :(

Comment: It looks like a design pattern. Do you have a name for this pattern?

Comment: @HelloRacoon: it's neitehr a pattern that I see often nor I could give a name, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one word: *Python syntax*

The function `something_callable` accept any keyword argument, ignores it and return a function taking one argument named `something`, possible other keywords arguments and returns `something`.

When you write `what = test_class.call()` it is (per syntax) the same thing as `Test_class.call(test_class)` so it returns... `test_class`.

This is enough to explain why `what == test_class` is True. In fact `what is test_class` is also True...

And when you write `what = test_class.call(something=None)` it is the same thing as:

```
what = Test_class.call(test_class, something=None)
```

As the first parameter for `Test_class.call` is named `something` you are trying to pass twice the same parameter. Hence the error.